# xcrun simctl status_bar not working on Xcode 14.1

Tags: xcode, terminal, statusbar, simulator

After upgrading to Xcode 14.1 on macOS 13.0.1 the command for changing my status bar on the simulator doesn't work anymore. The terminal seems to get the booted device, because the command
`xcrun simctl shutdown "booted"` does work.

If I try `xcrun simctl status_bar "booted" override --time 9:41`  nothing happens though. I tried multiple simulators, none of them showed the changes for the status bar.

Is this a known bug or am I missing something?

### Update

The issue has been fixed in Xcode 15.3! We can now use the following command to perfectly adjust the status bar:

```
xcrun simctl status_bar "booted" override --time 9:41 --dataNetwork wifi --wifiMode active --wifiBars 3 --cellularMode active --cellularBars 4 --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100
```

Comment: I have the same experience so I think this is a bug. On two separate VM images (one with Xcode 13 and the other 14) I get different results: The overrides work consistently on 13 and have no effect consistently on 14.
Moreover, running `xcrun simctl status_bar booted list` will show all overrides that I set correctly: The command runs successfully but has no effect.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with Xcode 14.3 (14E222b) – so the issue isn’t fixed by Apple.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in Xcode 15.3

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in Xcode. I wrote a bit more about what the actual problem is [here](https://federated.saagarjha.com/notice/AUwNsSsOOCWFc8qCvY) but as a workaround you can boot your simulator like so and it should go back to working: `SIMCTL_CHILD_SIMULATOR_RUNTIME_VERSION=16.0 xcrun simctl boot`

Answer (score 3):

Use iOS 16.0 simulator instead of 16.1 or newer. This can be added in Xcode -> Settings -> Platform

Answer (score 1):

This should be a known bug that was introduced since Xcode 14.1 (Xcode 14.2 doesn't work too). There's also a discussion thread at Apple Developer Forums. Refer to ["Can't change time in Xcode Simulator"](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720610).

The OP of that thread said ["Simulator Status Magic"](https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic) works, <s>but I tried without any luck. Maybe you can try it first.</s> I tried it and it worked as expected.

But in order to use Simulator Status Magic in Xcode 14.1, we need to run a script provided in the repo (as a reminder, **the simulator has to be running first**):

```
$ cd path/to/SimulatorStatusMagic
$ ./build_and_inject.sh booted
```

---

If it doesn't work for you as well, I think the only way left is to download Xcode 14.0 from [Software Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) page.

Downloading Simulator 16.0 from Xcode 14.1/2 might also work, but I didn't try because the process cost a long time on my side. And what's more, the shortcoming is whenever you upgrade to a new Xcode version in the future, you need to re-download Simulator 16.0 again. Who knows when this bug will be fixed.

<s>Personally, I will keep Xcode 14.0 for a while until Apple's developer team fixes this bug.</s> Btw, remember to rename the downloaded Xcode to "Xcode 14" before dragging it to your Application folder.

Comment: [SimulatorStatusMagic](https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic) worked with Xcode 14.3 and iOS 16.4 for me!

Comment: @alexkaessner it sounds great! I'll try next time when needed (I'm still using Xcode 14.2 at the moment).